# Make tasks fail in Azure Devops pipeline when git commands fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking for an elegant or inelegant solution for failing a step in ADO pipelines when git commands return unexpected and unwanted results. In general, I call git with a bash task, like so:

```
steps:
- bash: |    
    git merge ${{ parameters.sourceBranch }}
```

If the merge fails, I would like this step to fail in my ADO pipeline. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `git merge` exits nonzero on conflicts or other failures; how you get azure to respect the exit status from commands, as reported by bash, I don't know. Note that bash has its own exit status and the default is to exit with the status from the last-executed command, so given what you've shown here, if `git merge` exits with status 1, `bash` would also exit with status 1. In general 0 = success and any nonzero value = failure, but we're back to "what the heck does Azure do" (which I have no idea).

Comment: @Zeek Aran can I check - have you tried running the task as-is, and finding out what the pipeline does when the merge fails?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Yes, I'm here because some of my git commands have been silently failing for the last couple months. Oops! The setup is exactly as I have it above, and ADO doesn't care at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the result of the git merge command should be not successful on bash I created the below bash condition. If result is correct nothing will be done, else exit for the bash will be returned

```
if git merge ${{ parameters.sourceBranch }} > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo success
else
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This fails the step! Thank you. Can you explain this part? /dev/null 2>&1

It seems to eat the failure message. If possible, I'd like to have it return exit 1 on failure and also include the failure message from git.

Comment: @ZeekAran correct, you could do `msg=$(git merge ${{ parameters.sourceBranch }} 2>&1)` and then print the `$msg`

Answer (score 0):

Found a somewhat elegant solution just by setting a variable to the output:

```
git merge ${{ parameters.sourceBranch }}
status=$?
[ $status -eq 0 ] || exit $status
```

$? is the last status code. The next line says "if the last status was 0, continue on, else/or: exit with that status code".

Answer (score 0):

Would [failOnStderr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops#arguments) work? It looks like the bash step you're using is similar to script here.